# Simple_form: Remove outer label for an inline checkbox with label

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Using Simple_form 2.0.2

The simple form code using HAML:

```
= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, inline_label: 'Remember me'
```

But it renders this:

```
<div class="control-group boolean optional">
  <label class="boolean optional control-label" for="admin_remember_me">Remember me</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input name="admin[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <label class="checkbox"><input class="boolean optional" id="admin_remember_me" name="admin[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" />Remember me</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I remove that first label that's rendered, so that I only have the inline label?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use:

```
= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, inline_label: 'Remember me', label: false
```

Answer (score 27):

Found a solution after much Google fu.

Use `input_field` instead of `input` which won't automatically generate a label.

```
= f.input_field :remember_me, as: :boolean, inline_label: 'Remember me'
```

Comment: Just for reference, here's a solution that will work in erb `= f.input_field :remember_me, :as => :boolean, :inline_label => 'Remember me'`

Comment: @ScottBartell I think you mean in ruby pre 1.9 not erb. embrace the new. :)

Comment: problem with `input_field` is that it will not show validation errors.

Answer (score 11):

For whom it doesn't work

> = f.input_field ...

Use this way

> = f.check_box ...

Comment: This doesn't really apply to simple_form though, does it?

Comment: Yes, it does actually @Chris_Peters

Answer (score 7):

With simple_form 2.1.0 and rails 3.0.20, none of the solutions listed here worked (I don't want to use f.input_field because it's an admission of defeat).

The missing part is the **boolean_style** option:

```
options.merge!({label: false, boolean_style: :inline})
```

I suggest you create a custom input for this (e.g.: inline_checkbox)

boolean_style is configured as :nested by default, I think:

```
# Defaults to :nested for bootstrap config.
#   :inline => input + label
#   :nested => label > input
config.boolean_style = :nested
```

Comment: Is there an options for radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

```
.control-group.error .help-inline {
  display: none;
}
```

This should work, it works for me on rails 3.2 and simple_form 2.x+

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but inspired by gamov answer I have made this a custom wrapper from inline bootstrap checkbox in the initializer file '**config/simple_form_bootstrap.rb**':

```
config.wrappers :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
   b.use :html5
   b.optional :readonly

   b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'
   b.use :input
   b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
   b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
 end
```

which generates this html:

```
 <div class="form-group boolean optional user_admin">
    <label class="boolean optional col-sm-3 control-label" for="user_admin">Admin</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 checkbox-inline">
    <input name="user[admin]" value="0" type="hidden">
    <input class="boolean optional" id="user_admin" name="user[admin]" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </div>
```