# How can I get simple form to not wrap check_box in label tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How can I get simple form to not wrap check_box in label tag

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @project,
                             url: project_path(@project),
                             html: {
                               id: "project-form",
                               class: "form",
                             } do |f| %>

    <%= f.association :tasks,
                  collection: Task.options_for_select,
                  as: :check_boxes,
                  required: false %>

    <%= f.input :hold %>


  <% end %>
```

current result

```
<label for="task_ids_8">
  <input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="8" name="task_ids" id="task_ids_8">Structure</label>
```

desired result

```
<label for="task_ids_8">Structure</label>
<input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="8" name="task_ids" id="task_ids_8">
```

I need to know how to do this for the individual "hold" input and the collection.

Comment: Have you tried: `<%= f.check_box :hold %>` or `<%= f.input_field :hold %>` as [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18913719/3366016) for newer rails.

Comment: I have. For the individual inputs I will have to add an html label. That's fine. I'm still not sure how to address the collection though.

Comment: Setting the `boolean_style: :inline` according to the docs should do it.https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#stripping-away-all-wrapper-divs Other examples lean towards the same thing but with slightly different declarations.    `<%= f.association :tasks,
                  collection: Task.options_for_select,
                  as: :check_boxes,
                  required: false, boolean_style: :inline %>`

Comment: So that did get the check box out of the label, but the label is still clickable because it has the "for" attribute still :/

Comment: I just convinced product the labels should be clickable, because they should be clickable

Comment: good call. It is typically behavior to have the label clickable anyway.  Moving comments to answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the one-off checkbox you can use one of these:

```
<%= f.check_box :hold %>
```

or

```
<%= f.input_field :hold %>
```

as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18913719/3366016) for newer rails.

For the collection you can set the `boolean_style: :inline` according to the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#stripping-away-all-wrapper-divs). Other examples lean towards the same thing but with slightly different declarations.

Use this:

`<%= f.association :tasks, collection: Task.options_for_select, as: :check_boxes, required: false, boolean_style: :inline %>`